# Add my app activity instances to recents on Lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

This feature was introduced in Chrome on Lollipop. Chrome's tabs can be managed by Lollipop recents list.

How to implement similar functionality in my own app? Is there any new api for this?

Comment: You want multiple instances of your app in the recent tasks, the way chrome appears to have multiple instances in recent tasks?

Comment: Actually I have no idea how it was implemented in Chrome. When you choose new tab, it appears on recent apps list, instead of chrome tabs manager. On  Lollipop, Chrome does not have any tab manager, all new tabs go to recents instead. You can disable it and enable built in chrome tab manager, but this feature is available only on Lollipop. Maybe it's new program instance, but how can I do the same in my app?

Comment: P.S. Please don't vote down this question, it's not trivial problem! It must some kind of new Lollipop feature, Chrome is unable to do that on older system versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Overview Screen AKA Recent Tasks](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/recents.html)

> With the Android 5.0 release (API level 21), multiple instances of the same activity containing different documents may appear as tasks in the overview screen.

In API 21 they added [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT) to achieve this.

> Through the use of this flag, or its equivalent attribute, documentLaunchMode multiple instances of the same activity containing different documents will appear in the recent tasks list.

For usage see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/recents.html#flag-new-doc).